# Firebase + angularfire getting current user before controller loads

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebasesimplelogin

I'm following the [official examples](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html) to fetch the user before the angular controller is fired but the controller is never fired when using this method. If I remove the `resolve: state_resolver` line the controller fires which means my resolver has something wrong. Any ideas what am I doing wrong here?

```
.config(function($stateProvider) {
  var state_resolver;
  state_resolver = {
    "current_user": [
      "simpleLogin", function(simpleLogin) {
        return simpleLogin.$getCurrentUser();
      }
    ]
  };
  return $stateProvider.state("dash", {
    url: "/dash",
    templateUrl: "templates/dash.html",
    controller: "DashCtrl",
    resolve: state_resolver
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Romeo! It looks like we'll need a bit more due diligence to help you resolve this. Have you added a service called `simpleLogin` as explained in the routes example? Can you include that code here, as well as the controller? What errors are in your JavaScript console, what versions are we using?

Comment: Also, you should try handling the then(success, failed) methods in your resolve function and outputting them to console.log to see what's going on, or adding a breakpoint in your debugger.

Answer (score 0):

If the following example using $timeout works, then you probably have an issue with your simpleLogin service which does not respond.

```
.config(function($stateProvider) {
    var state_resolver;
    state_resolver = {
        "current_user": function($timeout) {
            return $timeout(function () {console.log('OK');}, 5000);
        }
    };
```

Comment: The array is present in their [examples](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html) (scroll down to "Using Simple Login with Routers")

Comment: OK, could you still test the version without the array, just to be sure?

Comment: Yeah I did before looking again at their examples actually :)

Comment: both the array notation and the non-array notation fail?

Comment: could you test using a simple $timeout as added in my response?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59893/discussion-between-apairet-and-romeo-mihalcea).